# Applying gravity to a bounded d3.js force layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a massive d3.js graph that works fine. There are a number of filters and on application of some the graph breaks into many sub graphs at times and while it breaks many sub graphs go out of bounds .

Hence I am trying to use gravity.

Below is how I bound my subgraph:

```
    var width = 1160,
      height = 700,
      radius = 6;
    var svg = d3.select(selector).append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height);

   var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) {
      return d.id;
    }).distance(40).strength(1))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
    .force(d3.gravity(0.25));
```

But this fails with:

```
  Uncaught ReferenceError: d3.gravity is not a function
```

So , I am confused about how exactly to apply gravity. New to d3.js.

Below is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vishy1988/2rrkyz9t/9/)

Comment: The last line should be .force(d3.gravity(0.25)); to get rid of that particular error.

Comment: did try that earlier. But still the same error

Comment: Well, the error message pretty much nails it: there is no such function as `d3.gravity()`. To simulate gravity in D3 v4 you may customize the [`d3.forceManyBody()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-force#forceManyBody) for your purposes or provide a custom-built force function like the `gravity()` function in Robert Monfera’s [Block].(https://bl.ocks.org/monfera/2d2809d8458ffb81cc9acab2e65ed4ef).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This custom gravity function did the trick:

```
     var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) {
      return d.id;
    }).distance(40).strength(1))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
    .force("gravity",gravity(0.25));


function gravity(alpha) {
  return function(d) {
    d.y += (d.cy - d.y) * alpha;
    d.x += (d.cx - d.x) * alpha;
  };
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is also another way of doing it with d3.v4 using:

```js
var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
  .force('x', d3.forceX(width / 2).strength(0.25))
  .force('y',  d3.forceY(height / 2).strength(0.25))
```

It applies gravity on the `x` and `y` axes. The higher the strength is, the denser the gravity on that axes will be.